# Get experience points and level from google plus profile or Get Data from google plus profile

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard, achievements

I am using google play game services in my game to get data and leaderboard scores from google leaderboard.

I noticed this screen in the leaderboard profile.

[image]

As you can see the name , and level and XP points.

I was wondering is there a way to get these data so that I can show it in my custom leaderboard.

I already got data like name and profile image.

but I couldnt find a way to get this game data.

Suggest me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting player's experience points and level ,first you have to fetch a local player that is currently signed in with your game.For this you should use  Player Manager of the GPGS sdk to get a Player object that contains your required information. 
Please check this link:
[Player API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Player.html)